# Why deos my "While" loop keep going on?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

My loop never stops, I can't seem to understand what is wrong. I'm doing
a project for my class and I'm new to loops so kind of confused. Please tell me how
to resolve this issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FracCalc {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); {
        boolean Quit = true;

            System.out.println("Welcome to FracCalc");
            System.out.println("Type expressions with fractions, and I will evaluate them");
        String answer = scan.nextLine();
        while (Quit = true) {

        if (answer.equals("Quit")){
          System.out.println("Thanks forr running FracCalc!");
          break;  

        }   else {
          System.out.println("I can only process 'Quit' for now");

        }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You're never setting the variable named "Quit" to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `String answer = scan.nextLine();` inside the loop.

Try the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FracCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to FracCalc");
        System.out.println("Type expressions with fractions, and I will evaluate them");

        String answer = scan.nextLine();

        do {

            if (answer.equals("Quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks forr running FracCalc!");
                break;  

            } else {
                System.out.println("I can only process 'Quit' for now");
            }

            answer = scan.nextLine();
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`Quit = true` will assign `true` to `Quit`, and return `true`. Thus, you're doing `while (true)`, a canonical infinite loop. And even if you were testing `Quit == true` (note double equality sign), you never assign it to `false`, as Izcd remarks. You could `break` out with your `if`, but `answer` is only assigned once, outside the loop.